# Cannot overload std::abs() for GCC 128 bit integer

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, x86, int128

I'm getting compiler errors when I call `abs()` with GCC's 128 bit type. My line looks like:

```
__extension__ using int128_t = __int128;

int128_t mantissa_;

// Other code

using namespace std;
int128_t temp = abs(mantissa_);
```

The error I'm getting locally is:

```
 error: call of overloaded ‘abs(const int128_t&)’ is ambiguous
     int128_t temp = abs(mantissa_);
/usr/include/stdlib.h:840:12: note: candidate: ‘int abs(int)’
  840 | extern int abs (int __x) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__)) __wur;

/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:56:3: note: candidate: ‘long int std::abs(long int)’
   56 |   abs(long __i) { return __builtin_labs(__i); }
      |   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:61:3: note: candidate: ‘long long int std::abs(long long int)’
   61 |   abs(long long __x) { return __builtin_llabs (__x); }
      |   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:71:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr double std::abs(double)’
   71 |   abs(double __x)
      |   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:75:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr float std::abs(float)’
   75 |   abs(float __x)
      |   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:79:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr long double std::abs(long double)’
   79 |   abs(long double __x)
```

so it's not considering my overload (below) as a candidate?

```
namespace std 
{
    __extension__ using int128_t = __int128;
    
    int128_t abs(int128_t x)
    {
        return x < 0 ? x * -1 : x;  // Not ideal but no builtin for 128
    }
}
```

Is the overload correct?

However, when I mock an example in Godbolt, even without overloading `abs()`, it compiles fine:

https://godbolt.org/z/P8T1fGxcK

```
#include <iostream>

__extension__ using int128_t = __int128;

struct Decimal
{
    Decimal(int128_t q) : mantissa_(q)
    {
        volatile int128_t x = abs(mantissa_);  // How is this compiling?
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    int128_t mantissa_;
};

int main()
{
    Decimal dec(-6);
}
```

Are Godbolt using a library like Abseil, they're providing a function and that's why it is compiling?

Comment: you cannot overload `std::abs`. Adding to namespace `std` is not allowed (with few exceptions)

Comment: why do you want to overload it? Why do you not call `myabs(__int128)` ?

Comment: Can you simplify your example and post it complete?  This https://onlinegdb.com/jlw0sEzKti compiles in onlinegdb.  Is your `std::abs(int128_t)` _declaration_ visible at the point of use?  Either by the definition or an `extern int128_t std::abs(int128_t);` declaration being before use in the same translation unit.  Clearly it will not be visible simply in including <cmath> or <cstdlib> if the definition is in a separate translation unit..

Comment: ... and what @463035818_is_not_a_number says - it is a bad idea even if it works.

Comment: Re your godbolt question, there is a button "Libraries" which show what libraries are used.  Abseil is available but not linked by default.  Your example fails in Godbolt using clang https://godbolt.org/z/f6EoGnva4.  My example does not https://godbolt.org/z/fzrboPvK3 so clearly a visibility thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. How to get `std::abs` working for `__int128`

The following only applies for gcc version >= 7.

For `__int128` gcc provides an overload of `std::abs` with the following code snippet:

[libstdc++-v3/include/bits/std_abs.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a23225fb4f764dfc3e3e729c7d7238f03f282aaa/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/std_abs.h#L83-L86)

```cpp
#if defined(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0)
  __extension__ inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0
  abs(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __x) { return __x >= 0 ? __x : -__x; }
#endif
```

(or one of the following 3 similar functions using `__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_1`, `__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_2`, etc...)

To get those macros defined you need to compile with gnu extensions enabled (i.e. not strict c++)
For this you need to build with `-std=gnu++20` instead of `-std=c++20` (or `-std=gnu++17`, `-std=gnu++14`, etc... depending on the c++ version you want to target)
(if no `-std=` option is given at all then gcc will default to `std=gnu++xx` (c++ version depending on compiler version))

When compiling with gnu extensions gcc will define those macros automatically for `__int128` (assuming gcc supports 128-bit ints for your target platform):
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Whfn58WYa)

```cpp
#define __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0 128
#define __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __int128
```

Unfortunately the c `abs` function-family (and the gcc builtin for it - `__builtin_abs`) do **not** support `__int128` at all, and calling them would result in truncation of the result value.

Example: (compiled with `-std=gnu++20 -Wconversion`):
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c7cYKafa1)

```cpp
#include <cmath>

__extension__ using int128_t = __int128;

int128_t mantissa_;

int main() {
    {
        using namespace std;
        // OK - calls std::abs(__int128)
        int128_t foo = abs(mantissa_);
    }

    // OK - calls std::abs(__int128)
    int128_t bar = std::abs(mantissa_);

    // WARNING: calls abs(int) --> truncation
    int128_t baz = abs(mantissa_);

    // WARNING: calls abs(int) --> truncation
    int128_t foobar = __builtin_abs(mantissa_);
}
```

---

#### 2. Why the godbolt compiles

The [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P8T1fGxcK) you provided compiles due to it calling the c function [`int abs(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)
(the code does not include `using namespace std;`, so `std::abs` is not visible)

The c `abs`-family of functions have different names for the possible types, so a call to `abs()` with `__int128` as argument will not be ambigous (but will result in truncation to `int`):

```cpp
int        abs  ( int n );
long       labs ( long n );
long long  llabs( long long n );

/* floating-point versions would be fabs, ... */
```

The c++-variant of `abs` - [`std::abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) - is implemented with overloads instead, so a call to `std::abs` with `__int128` will be ambigous, assuming there is no overload for `__int128` defined.
(`__int128 -> long long`, `__int128 -> long`, `__int128 -> int`, etc... would be *Integral conversions*; `__int128 -> double`, `__int128 -> float`, etc.. would be *Floating-integral conversions*. Both *Integral conversions* and *Floating-integral conversions* and have the same rank ([*Conversion*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.best.ics#over.ics.scs-3)), so none of those overloads would be a better match than any other -> ambigous)

```cpp
namespace std {
    int       abs( int n );
    long      abs( long n );
    long long abs( long long n );

    /* more overloads of abs for floating-point types */
}
```

---

#### 3. Manually adding the `std::abs` function

Note that adding declarations to `std` is [generally undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_declarations_to_std) (with a few exceptions), so i would not recommend this.

Here's a comparison of the gcc version vs your version:

```cpp
// version provided by gcc (when compiling with gnu extensions)
// (macros substituted for better readability)
namespace std {
    __extension__ inline constexpr __int128 abs(__int128 __x) {
        return __x >= 0 ? __x : -__x;
    }
}

// your version
namespace std {
    __extension__ using int128_t = __int128;
    
    int128_t abs(int128_t x)
    {
        return x < 0 ? x * -1 : x;  // Not ideal but no builtin for 128
    }
}
```

They're functionally identical, the ternary condition is just inverted and you're multiplying by negative one whereas gcc uses the unary minus operator.

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/svrGsznfK)

Comment: I'm using `__builtin_abs` but i think it's getting interpreted as `int` because I'm getting warnings `warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
  197 |             return __builtin_abs(x);`.  Code is `T template<class T>` then `T my_abs(T x) const` then `return __builtin_abs(x);`

Comment: @intrigued_66 sorry i messed up big time - i accidentially read the code for the `fabs`-builtin instead of `abs` (missed the f in the front), so unfortunately what i stated only applies to `__float128`, but not `__int128`. I'm increadibly sorry for this mistake, i'll update my post within the next hour with the correct information.

Comment: No worries. Just thinking.... is there not a way of just over-writing the sign bit? That must be faster than a CMOV and multiplication?

Comment: @intrigued_66 unfortunately it's not that simple for two's complement. IEEE-754 floats do have a dedicated sign bit, so for those a simple and can be used to set the sign bit to zero ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eqffYTeEb) - note how `.LC0` and `.LC1` are bitmasks with all but 1 bit set (the sign-bit)). For two's complement it's a bit more tricky; the most significant bit denotes if the number is positive or negative, but the negative values are ordered inversely to the positive ones - so simply flipping the most significant bit will not work: [examples](https://godbolt.org/z/1b3MrPa9Y)

Comment: The usual method for implementing `abs` in two's complement is to invert the value and add 1, i.e.: `abs(x) == x >= 0 ? x : (~x + 1)` ([here's a simple explanation](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html#whyworks) of why this is the case) - this is also what gcc will produce for both your abs implementation and it's builtin one (assuming you're compiling with optimizations enabled): [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h486c91TE) (all 4 functions produce the same instructions)

Comment: due to x64 not having 128-bit registers gcc will use 2 64-bit registers to represent `_int128` - `rdi` + `rsi` are the `x` parameter, and `rax` + `rdx` will be used for the return value in the linked godbolt. So there are 2 `neg`'s (to invert both registers), one `adc` to add one and 2 `cmov`'s, to ensure we only return the inverted result in case the original number was negative.